# R - multiple linear regression, generating an extra variable with a specific regression coefficient

Tags: r, simulation, linear-regression

I want to run a simulated power analysis for a dataset I have. Let's assume the dataset has four variables (column names of the dataset):

Y - which is the dependent variable, is continuous and normally distributed.

X1 - an independent variable, is continuous and has a normal distribution.

X2 - an independent variable, is continous and is NOT normally distributed.

X3 - an independent variable, is continous and is NOT normally distributed.

Now, this data consists of 5000 rows, so there are  5000 entries.

I've run a linear regression using the following formula:

`summary(lm( Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3))`, and determined the regression coefficients of X1, X2, and X3 to be B1, B2, and B3 respectively.

I now have a fifth variable (x4) which I don't have access to but I believe is normally distributed. Now, the linear model can be updated using the following formula:

`lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4)`, with the regression coefficient of B4.

I don't know what B4 is, but I have various scenarious where B4 is between 0.2 - 0.5.

I want to run monte-carlo simulations to check what sample size is required to achieve 80% power at various B4. To do this, I need to generate a normally distributed variable that can simulate x4, and and has a regression coefficient of B4. Is there any way to generate this in R?

Comment: you might want to look into `greta`. More info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/greta/vignettes/get_started.html)

Comment: When you add a fourth variable to the equation, the coefficients B1, B2 and B3 will change. As you explained in the question: is seems you are assuming the B1*x1+B2*x2+B3*x2 = B1*x1+B2*x2+B3*x2+ 0.3*x4. For this to work x4 will need to be zero or coefficients on the right side needs to change.  I not sure how you are going to perform the analysis when B1, B2, B3 and x4 are all unknown.

Comment: @Dave2e Taking expectation on both sides, you've hit the nail on the head.  If the X's are independent there won't be any covariance terms,  so the common terms will cancel, leaving B4*E[X4] = 0.  In that case B4 = 0 or E[X4] = 0 (these are not mutually exclusive).  If B4 is non-zero, all X4 does is inflate the residuals and reduce R-square.  The other alternative is that X4 is correlated with the other X's, in which case estimation of B1, B2, and B3 will be impacted, but there's no way to tell what the effect is without real data.